# How to combine socket.io with some of the simple static http servers on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have created a Socket.IO application and I even already got some interactivity working. But I still host static content on Apache HTTP server (localhost, XAMPP bundle). Actually when running Node.js, this is my working directory:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\game>node nodeGame.js
```

I'd like to move it all somewhere else, probably convert it into npm package and use Node.js to serve HTML and JavaScript files to user. It would be best if I could just install some simple handler that could be passed into `http`. Something like:

```
  var http = Http.Server(require("really-simple-http-server"));
  var io = SocketIo(http);
  // Sockets below
```

None of the servers I found on StackOverflow seemed that simple, so which is most suitable for this purpose and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket.io with the Express framework (using Express as your web server) and then use `express.static()` to serve static files:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// set up static file serving from the public directory
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Details on the options for serving static files with Express are [here](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).